# Como faço para imprimir a localização (linha e coluna) do maior valor dentro de uma matriz?

Tags: python-3.x, matriz, pycharm

Bom dia, não estou conseguindo completar o meu código, já utilizei o For i in range e o for j in range, porém não consigo completar o código pois preciso armazenar o resultado em outra variável e logo em seguida ver se os resultados são maiores que o valor x, e depois fazer o print para me mostrar a coluna e a linha que está o maior valor, estou utilizando o Python juntamente com o Pycharm 2016.1

```
matriz = [[11,12,13,14]
          [15,16,17,18]
          [19,20,21,22]]

for i in range(matriz.__len__()):
    for j in range(matriz.__len__()):

    if matriz [i][j]>x:
```

Comment: Coloque o código relevante que tem por favor

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Compartilhe o seu código de modo a facilitar que as pessoas te ajudem.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, o matriz não está aceitando aqui como uma variável, no pycharm ele já aceita

Comment: Pode completar o que está dentro do if sff. Dá algum erro? Qual?

Comment: tá dando este erro,     for i in range(matriz.__len__()):
    ^
                                  IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Isso tem a haver com o espaçamento no princípio da linha

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como pegar o maior valor de uma matriz / vetor em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207150/como-pegar-o-maior-valor-de-uma-matriz-vetor-em-python)

Answer (score -1):

```
def maior(matriz):
    maior, linha, coluna = 0,0,0
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        for j in range(len(matriz)):
            if matriz[i][j] > maior:
                linha = i
                coluna = j
                maior = matriz[i][j]
    return "Maior Valor %d  posicao matriz[%d][%d]" % (maior,linha,coluna)
```