# Como pegar o maior valor de uma matriz / vetor em python?

Tags: python, array, matriz

como faço pra pegar o maior valor de uma matriz ou vetor?

Por exemplo, neste exercício tenho que fazer uma matriz 4x4 e retornar a **linha e coluna do maior elemento**, porém parei aí.

```
m = []
for i in range(4):
    linha = []
    for j in range(4):
        linha.append(int(input()))
        m.append(linha)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeira coisa que você precisa notar é que a criação da matriz está errada, você precisa adicionar uma nova linha depois que já tiver inserido valores nas quatro posições dela, pra isso a linha `m.append(linha)` precisa estar fora do segundo `for`.

Encontrar o maior valor é simples, é só usar a função `max` combinada com *list comprehension*, basicamente, é criada uma nova coleção (linear, desta vez) com todos os elementos (sem se preocupar com suas linhas e colunas) e nesta coleção linear é procurado o maior valor.

```
maior = max([valor for linha in m for valor in linha])
```

Mas como você precisa encontrar os índices dele (linha e coluna), eu fiz um código que passa por todos os elementos, verifica qual é o maior e guarda a linha e a coluna dele.

Existe um jeito mais simples de se fazer, já que o Python tem essa filosofia de ser simplista? Muito provavelmente sim, mas eu não faço ideia de como seria

```
m = []
for i in range(4):
    linha = []
    for j in range(4):
        linha.append(int(input()))

    m.append(linha)

maior_linha = 0
maior_coluna = 0
maior = m[0][0]
for l in range(4):
    for c in range(4):        
        if maior < m[l][c]:
            maior = m[l][c]
            maior_linha = l
            maior_coluna = c

print('linha do maior: {}\ncoluna do maior: {}'.format(maior_linha, maior_coluna))
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/IPab/8)

Comment: É realmente uma boa dar a resposta da lição de casa em vez de dar meios para se chegar a solução?

Comment: @ppalacios Eu expliquei tudo o que tá feito, se ele quer estudar vai ler o código e minha explicação e se ficar com dúvidas pode comentar ou até mesmo ir no chat e conversar comigo. Se ele não quiser aprender existem 1001 maneiras de conseguir o resultado de qualquer forma, não vai ser uma resposta do SOpt que vai evitar isso. Além disso, o AP mostrou que está parado no ponto determinado e que precisa de ajuda, em nenhum momento a pergunta me pareceu um "façam pra mim".

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente, é isso para uma linha:

```
max(linha)
```

E para uma matriz:

```
max([valor for linha in matriz for valor in linha])
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ainda fazer a verificação em tempo real, a cada valor lido. Isso evitará que você crie laços de repetição para a definição da matriz e outros laços de repetição para buscar o maior valor.

Veja o exemplo:

```
m = []               # Matriz
max = None           # Armazena o maior valor
position = (0, 0)    # Armazena a posição do maior valor

# Define 4 linhas na matriz:
for i in range(4):

    # Linha da matriz:
    linha = []

    # Define 4 colunas na matriz:
    for j in range(4):

        # Lê o valor a ser inserido:
        value = int(input("Valor da posição ({}, {}):".format(i, j)))

        # Verifica se o valor é maior que o máximo atual:
        if max is None or value > max:

            # Sim, então altera o valor do máximo e de sua posição
            max = value
            position = (i, j)

        # Adiciona o valor à linha:
        linha.append(value)

        # Adiciona a linha na matriz:
        m.append(linha)

# Exibe a posição do maior valor:
print("O maior valor está na posição {} e vale {}".format(position, max))
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/IPmv/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
maior_linha = matriz.index(max(matriz))
maior_coluna = matriz[maior_linha].index(max(matriz[maior_linha]))
print(f'localização maior valor: ({maior_linha}, {maior_coluna})')
```

Essa é a forma mais simples que eu consegui pensar. Gostaria de colocar todo o código aqui para te ajudar a criar e imprimir bem uma matriz mas não conheço essa plataforma e ter que colocar linha por linha do código é tenso hauhaua qlqr coisa chama que eu te mando!